# How to keep an Airflow DAG trailing behind by X days?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I currently have an Airflow DAG which runs on a daily schedule  `0 4 * * *`. Typically with this schedule, each daily run triggered will be for an `execution_date` of  `(current_date in UTC) - 1 day`. However I would like the DAG runs to be triggered for  `(current_date in UTC) - 1 day - X days`.

I tried setting the DAG's `end_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)` but this led to  errors where the upcoming scheduled DAG run would "succeed" without running any of its tasks.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

In your DAG you can modify the date, `data_interval_start` will have the same value as `ds`.

```
{{ data_interval_start + macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(days=-7) }}
```

Edit:
You can have two DAGs, trigger DAG and the actual DAG. Trigger DAG will use `TriggerDagRunOperator` and pass `execution_date` param to the actual DAG. You can pass anything as `execution_date`.

Comment: thanks for the help - the thing is that while we can derive the correct date in the DAG logic, we'd like to have `ds` reflect it instead. That way we can see in the UI each DAG Run corresponds to the processing of data for that specific day, rather than have inconsistency between the date that the logic uses vs. the execution date.

Comment: I think there is no clean way to do that, you will need to trigger backfill jobs.

Comment: I've edited the answer. There's one more method to override execution date but I think TriggerDagRunOperator is simper.